# SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt, passport.js

> I am trying to create a route for register by using passportjs. On
>   request using postman , I am getting this error : SyntaxError:
>   Unexpected token } in JSON at position 119
>     at
>   JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
>
> Below is my code :

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const gravatar = require("gravatar");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const keys = require("../config/keys");
const passport = require("passport");
//load input validation
const validateRegisterInput = require("../validation/register");
//user model
const User = require("../models/User");

router.get("/test", (req, res) => res.json({ msg: "user route works" }));

//post - api/users/register
router.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  const { errors, isValid } = validateRegisterInput(req.body);
  //check validation
  if (!isValid) {
    return res.status(400).json(errors);
  }
  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).then(user => {
    if (user) {
      errors.email = "Email already exists";
      return res.status(400).json(errors);
    } else {
      const avatar = gravatar.url(req.body.email, {
        s: "200", // Size
        r: "pg", // Rating
        d: "mm" // Default
      });

      const newUser = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        avatar
      });


      bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          newUser.password = hash;
          newUser
            .save()
            .then(user => res.json(user))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        });
      });
    }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

> Below is my request using postman :

```
{
  "name":"Harry",
  "email": "harrypotter@gmail.com",
  "password" : "harry",
  "avatar" : "https://image.jpg",
}
```

Comment: Can you say what is the code at line `119`

Comment: remove the comma after  `"..image.jpg"`

Comment: use this:`{
  "name":"Harry",
  "email": "harrypotter@gmail.com",
  "password" : "harry",
  "avatar" : "https://image.jpg"
}`

Comment: I removed comma after '' ..image.jpg'' , I got this error TypeError: Expected string but received a undefined.

Comment: your newUser object is not completed. avatar: req.body.avatar is missing

Comment: on updating with avatar: req.body.avatar , I still get this error TypeError: Expected string but received a undefined.<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at assertString (

Comment: Can you please share the new error logs. That will help making a better understanding as the error could be in some other place.

Comment: TypeError: Expected string but received a undefined.<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at assertString (D:\PROJECTS\mern-socialntwk\node_modules\validator\lib\util\assertString.js:28:11)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Object.isEmpty

Comment: Is there any method in postman while using passportjs

Comment: Seems like this error is coming from node_modules's validator package. It just add some validations on your inputs, reference is https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator. Please, post the code of the snippet where you are using this library.

Comment: https://github.com/4bhishekKasam/social-platform-MERN-

Comment: Added my answer and it worked for me. Please, accept and upvote the answer if it works for you else let me know the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185728/discussion-between-ankurjat-and-abhishek-konnur).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code at you need to send password2 in body. So, use below curl for request and you will be fine.

> curl -X POST \   http://localhost:8080/api/users/register \   -H
>   'Cache-Control: no-cache' \   -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
>   -H 'Postman-Token: c437c084-def1-427f-bf43-33b92a747244' \   -d '{   "name":"Harry",   "email": "harrypotter@gmail.com",   "password" :
>   "harry12",   "password2" : "harry12",   "avatar" : "https://image.jpg"
>   }'

Comment: const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  avatar: { type: String },
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

Comment: this is my schema , as I see there is no password2 ,   its only in my validation

Comment: Yes, in your validation you are checking existance of "password2" that is not there in your request body. Other than that there is another error in is-empt.js file. add "return" in front of your code else you will get undefined always.

Comment: So, as there is no "password2" in your request body so, line 30 of register.js was giving the error. Sending "password2" in the request will fix this error.

Comment: added password2 in body and in schema, also added return in is-empty.js yet I get this error SyntaxError: Unexpected token &#39; in JSON at position 143

Comment: please, use the above curl or import it in your postman or share your request body so that we can help you solving that issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
app.use(express.json({strict:false,type:'mixed'}))
```